# One query to search in multiple types documents

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have three types of documents in my database. Suppose they store some information about cars. They are:

- cars/id/factoryId (general info about car that was manufactured in some factory),
- cars/id/factoryId/parts/partname (specific info about part1name used in car),
- cars/id/factoryId/history (some information about history).

For example this documents could have ids like this:

- cars/123/1/parts/partname1,
- cars/123/2/parts/partname1,
- cars/123/1/parts/partname2,
- cars/123/1,
- cars/123/1/history.

For given id I would like to write a query in c# that finds only documents of form cars/id/factoryId/parts/partname (in the above example that would be documents first, second and third). I am able to get all possible values for factoryId and use foreach to create multiple queries. Is it possible write only one query?

This is code with foreach loop:

```
foreach (var id in factoryIds)
{
    var collection = session.Advanced.LoadStartingWith<CarPart>(prefix + id + "/parts");
    result.AddRange(collection);
}
```

My database version is 3.0 and I use RavenDB.Client package to connect to database in c# code.

Comment: Which database, which or mapper, which ...

Comment: I updated question with database and client information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use your previous approach, but do that lazily.
That means that only a single request will be sent to the server.

See:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/session/loading-entities#loadstartingwith